# How accurately does sepolia gas/transaction price correlate with ETH

Tags: ether, gas-price, fees, sepolia

I'm currently using Sepolia testnet while learning how to mint nft's through javascript, and wondering how accurate the gas price/transaction fee's are for when I switch to using real ETH.

I'm making pretty simple NFT's, basically just a custom jpg from pinata as the image and some basic metadata, right now the gas price is showing around 1 GWEI and transaction fee as .0001 ETH. Does this sound right or what ranges should I expect from using real ETH?

Answer (score 0):

The limit used will stay the same, the amount of gwei per unit of gas to reach that limit will depend on block utilisation at the time they make the call.

So you can estimate current cost for the user on mainnet by taking a current gas fee and multiplying it by the limit used for your contract call.

For example if current avrg price on mainnet is 40 gwei and we assume that is what the user selects in metamask.
If your contract consumed 80,000 units of gas to make the call.

- ((40000000000 * 80000)/10**18) = 0.0032
- 0.0032 * 1850 (eth price) = $5.92